# How to create Pipeline endpoint in Azure machine learning using CLI (v2) SDK?

Tags: command-line-interface, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML, using python SDK we are able to create and publish pipeline endpoints successfully.

We are trying to create a pipeline endpoint using CLI (v2) but, we are only able to create job using YAML specification file.

```
az ml job create --file my_job_definition.yaml
```

Is there any document or command/code available for creating and publish pipeline endpoints in Azure ML using CLI (v2).

Answer (score 0):

With AML SDKv2 there is no pipeline endpoint entity concept anymore, see table below:

[image]

Source and reference how to upgrade pipeline endpoints with sdk v2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-deploy-pipelines?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=v1

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no direct command or code available for creating and publishing **pipeline endpoints** in Azure ML using CLI (v2). You can publish pipeline endpoint with [PythonSDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-pipelines?view=azureml-api-1).

Alternately, you can publish endpoints with existing pipeline job in Azure ML using CLI (v2) with **batch endpoints**.
You can follow below steps to create the endpoint with pipeline job in Azure CLI:

Create the pipeline job with `pipeline.yml` file:

```
JOB_NAME=$(az ml job create -f pipeline.yml --query name -o tsv)
```

Create the endpoint with `endpoint.yml` file:

```
az ml batch-endpoint create --name $ENDPOINT_NAME  -f endpoint.yml
```

Create a deployment with `ENDPOINT_NAME`, `JOB_NAME` and `deployment.yml`:

```
az ml batch-deployment create --endpoint $ENDPOINT_NAME --set job_definition=azureml:$JOB_NAME -f deployment.yml
```

[Endpoint is Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpoOQ.png)

For more details you can refer to following reference documents:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-pipeline-from-job?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-training-pipeline?view=azureml-api-2

Comment: It is also possible to publish batch endpoints via sdk2 by now, see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-deploy-pipelines?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=v2.